# Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ with $f(0) < 0$ and $f(1)>0$. If $N = \{x : f(x) < 0\}$ and $c = \sup N$, show that $f(c) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) \lt 0$ and $f(1)\gt 0$. If $N = \lbrace  x : f(x) \lt 0\rbrace$ and $c = \sup N$, show that $f(c) = 0$.

I want to use IVT, but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you know about compactness? The closure of $N$ is compact, and the continuous image of a compact set is compact. If you've never heard of compactness, then I'm sorry that this is of no help.

Comment: You can also deduce a contradiction to the fact that for if $f(c)>0$ then there's a neighbourhood of $c$ (say$B$) such that for every $x\in B$, we have $f(x)>0$ (and similarly if you assume that $f(c)<0$).

Comment: Brandon's hint is right on the money, and avoids all mention of compactness, which keeps things simple.

Comment: So since there exists a neighborhood around c, c cannot be the supremum of N.

Comment: "I want to use IVT..." Do you?  I am willing to bet that you are actually trying to *prove* IVT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $N$ is nonempty and bounded, so indeed $\sup N=c$ exists. We know either $f(c)>0,<0$ or $=0$, so we'll aim to prove that the first two options are inadmissible.

So, suppose that $f(c)<0$. In particular, $c< 1$. By continuity, we can find $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)<0$ on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Why does this contradict that $c=\sup N$?

Now suppose that $f(c)>0$. Then we can find $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>0$ on $(c-\delta,c]$. Why does this contradict that $c=\sup N$?

**ADD** Careful! The arguments for each case are slightly different. In the first case, we obtain an element greater than $c$ for which $f(x)>0$, contradicting $c$ is *an* upper bound.
In the second case, we obtain that $f(x)$ is positive over $(c-\delta,c]$. This means no point of $N$ lies to the right of $c-\delta$, so $c-\delta$ is an upper bound smaller than $c$, contradicting $c$ is the *greatest* upper bound.

Comment: Does it contradict that c is the sup? Because if you have such a $\delta$ then you could choose $c_1=c+\frac{\delta}{2}$, which is clearly bigger than $c$? Additionally, you can find a $\delta>0$ for $\epsilon=-f(c)$ as then for that $\delta$ $f(x)$ is less than 0, right?

Comment: Since f(c+d)<0, c cannot be the supremum because c+d is an element of N and larger than c. Since f(c-d)>0, then c could not be the supremum of N because c-d is not an element of N but is smaller than c. Then, f(c)=0. Thank you!